# Not able to run app on Expo start with React-Native-Paper

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-paper

i am using React-Native using **Expo-cli**. I've also installed a library **React-Native-Paper**. When i run (expo start) my code without importing React-Native-Paper component it runs fine, but as i import even a single component from React-Native-Paper (lets say PaperProvider) i get the following error..
[image]

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
        env: {
            production: {
                plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel.js'],
            },
        },
    };
};
```

Please help.!

Comment: Remove the keyword type and import like import {Fonts} from '../types'. Also if you want to export type you can do export type Fonts = { //Some Code }.

Comment: The type error is from the react-native-paper library's file in node modules. I think my babel is not converting typeScript code of library to js, thats why this error is arising.